Display Third-Party Services As New Service in Zipkin Dependency Graph
I've checked this example Name an external dependency in Zipkin to have it drawn but it is manuel and doesn't work properly.
I need to display every third party services as distinct service in Zipkin. Is it possible?
For example,
I have contact with Database, Redis, example.com... All of them are shown as single-service in Zipkin but I need to show them as separated service.
MyController:
@GetMapping("all")
public ResponseEntity<List<TodoResponseDto>> getAllTodos() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(todoService.all());
}

MyService:
@Override
public List<TodoAggregate> all() {
    Span span = tracer.nextSpan().name("ex-client-test")
            .annotate("trial")
            .remoteServiceName("external-client-service-test")
            .kind(Span.Kind.CLIENT);
    try(Tracer.SpanInScope ws = tracer.withSpanInScope(span.start())) {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TodoAggregate>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
        ResponseEntity<List<TodoAggregate>> response = restTemplate.exchange(TODOS_URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, responseType);

        if (response.getBody() == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected response..."); //specify Exception
        }
        // add any tags / annotations on the span
        return response.getBody();
    } finally {
        span.finish();
    }
}

My properties:
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://${ZIPKIN_HOST:localhost}:9411/api/v2/spans
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
management.metrics.tags.application=${spring.application.name}

My dependencies:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
</dependency>

Output:

But I need to see restTemplate call as new service-name.
